# Are fixed position buffers a good use case for Pin?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm writing some code that shares buffers between Rust and the Linux kernel. After the buffer is registered, its memory location should never move. Since the API takes a `*mut u8` (actually a `libc::iovec`) but doesn't enforce the fixed memory location constraint, it works fine if I represent the buffer as `RefCell<Vec<u8>>`, `Arc<RefCell<Vec<u8>>>`, or `Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>`. (But the Rust code actually never writes to the buffers.)

Does `Pin` offer additional safety against data moving in this use case? I think it may not, since one of the major risks is calling `resize()` and growing the vector, but I do intend to call `resize()` without growing the vector. The code works, but I'm interested in writing this the most correct way.

Comment: If you never resize the buffer, it might make more sense to represent it as a `RefCell<&[u8]>` (or `RefCell<&[u8; SIZE]>` if the size is known at compile-time). Also you say you never write to the buffer, so you don't really need the `RefCell` and a plain `&[u8]` should suffice.

Comment: @Jmb Conversion from &[u8] to *mut u8 and sending by FFI is bad idea. Rust expects that shared reference never changes.

Comment: @Jmb I do resize it, but I don't really need to--I could track the expected data length as a separate variable.

Comment: @piojo If you resize it, then it may move when you do. Unless you resize it by deconstructing the `Vec` an reconstructing a new one with the new size, which you can do with a slice too…

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros good point, so a `RefCell` or `Mutex` is indeed required to ensure that there are no outstanding read references when the FFI code writes to the buffer.

Comment: @Jmb The docs say resizing it down doesn't deallocate the space. And resizing up but within the capacity shouldn't do anything. And there's no way for Rust to know nothing's reading while the kernel writes to the buffers. But it's easy for a human to know, since nothing reads the buffer until the kernel says data has been written.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about Pin but it is mostly useful for self-referential structs and coroutines AFAIK.

For you case, I would just create a struct which enforces invariant about data movement. E.g.:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct MyData{
   data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl MyData{
   fn with_capacity(cap: usize)->Self{
      Self{data: Vec::with_capacity(cap)}
   }

   fn resize(&mut self, new_len: usize, val_to_set: u8){
      let old_ptr = self.data.as_ptr();
      // Enforce invariant that memory never moves.
      assert!(new_len <= self.data.capacity());
      self.data.resize(new_len, val_to_set);
      debug_assert_eq!(old_ptr, self.data.as_ptr());
   }
}

// To get access to bytes
impl Deref for MyData{
    type Target = [u8];
    
    fn deref(&self)->&[u8]{
        &*self.data
    }
}

impl DerefMut for MyData{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self)->&mut[u8]{
        &mut *self.data
    }
}
```

This struct enforces that bytes never move without involving Pin.

And you can wrap it into RefCell.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something like this, but with `[u8; _]` as the wrapped type instead of `Vec`. I kept the size as a private member variable and returned `self.data[..size]` in `deref` and `deref_mut`. The code is simpler that way, with `resize()` just making a check and changing an int. Though I then lost the simplicity by copying the `deref`/`deref_mut` implementations from `Vec` to ensure there's no speed penalty.

Comment: I think, speed difference in neglible.

Comment: >[u8; _]

You cannot use it like that if you want to never move bytes because those bytes would be stored inline and moved with the struct itself. You should use either `Box<[u8; N]>`, `Box<[u8]>` or `Vec<u8>`.
The key idea of my answer is that bytes stored in heap and any move of wrapper cannot move them.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that benefit, thanks! Though I can't change it, due to wanting to get some possible advantage from `#[repr(C, align(4096))]`.

Comment: `Pin` is definitely useful for unmovable (i.e. _pinned_) memory locations. If there is already a in the middle (e.g. `Vec`), then a newtype would work. However, since the OP wants an array, using a newtype is effectively duplicating `Pin`'s functionality - this is exactly what `Pin` is designed for, and `Box::pin()`, for example, would work well (or you can go without `Box` and use unsafe code).